# Bone Heat Weight Error: Blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting, error

Trying to parent the Mesh to the Armature I've made for this giant robot we're trying to test poses for in a game I'm making.

I've never done this before, so I've mostly been following tutorials.  I had to join the parts of the robot together to get a single mesh to work with.  I've googled around and none of the solutions I've found for this issue have worked for me, I removed the doubled vertices, and I'm not sure what else to do.

To make matters worse, I accidentally saved after I tried to parent the mesh, and now I'm stuck with this giant Horizontal mesh and my tiny little skeleton and I have no idea how to fix it. Can anyone give me some pointers on this? Or point me to a good video to sort it out?

The problem is that when I try to join the mesh to the armature, the Mesh grows gigantic and rotates 90 degrees to face the sky.  And I get the Bone Heat Weight Error, and it doesn't come together correctly.

Comment: i'm sorry, I'm not sure what your problem is,  what went wrong when you joined the parts together?

Comment: This is what your question says, I think you forgot to put in the problem **I had to join the parts of the robot together to get a single mesh to work with. I've googled around and none of the solutions I've found for this issue have worked for me,**

Comment: Thank you, I've edited it to be more specific.

Comment: try pressing **ctrl + A** and selecting **rotation** and **scale**.  I'm not sure if it will work.